# JavaScript More Efficient code to hide all element expect cloest

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have about 20 Forms. When A button the closes form should unhide.

And all the other forms should remain hidden. '

This is the way  i was doing it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );

      $(".toggle-new-form1").click(function() {
    $(".new-form1").toggleClass("hidden");
    // $("input[name='union_name']").focus();
  });
      $(".toggle-new-form2").click(function() {
    $(".new-form2").toggleClass("hidden");
    // $("input[name='union_name']").focus();
  });


});
```

This is sample of html

```
    <div class="form-group" style="">
    <label >Email:</label>
    <button type="button" id="new" style="margin-top:7px;"  class="toggle-new-form pull-right btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
    <p> example@gmail.com  </p>
    </div>
    <form  id="name-form" class="new-form1 hidden" method="POST"  action="">
    <input id="email">
<button type="submit"> Submit </button> 
    </form>
```

But i am having trouble hiding previously activated forms.

Is there anyway to make this more efficient and hide previously activated forms.

I have tryed this as well

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );

      $(".toggle-new-form").click(function() {
    $(".new-form").addClass("hidden");
     $(this).closest( ".new-form" ).removeClass( "hidden" )
  });


});
</script>
```

I dont know how its working

Js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0p2brLww/2/

Comment: You have 20 **hidden** forms... when a button is clicked the form unhides?

Comment: can you provide more detail, if possible with a fiddle.

Comment: Would you mind putting together a basic working fiddle of what you have? Other than that, I would suggest at looking at the `.each()` functionality in jQuery. You would essentially create a function that closes all open forms, and then run the function whenever you click on your toggle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0p2brLww/2/ here is a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this a single click event for all the buttons+forms

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('[class^="toggle-new-form"]').click(function() {
       var el = $(this).parent().next();
           $('[class^="new-form"]').not(el).addClass('hidden');
           el.toggleClass("hidden");
     //$(this).parent().next().find("input[name='union_name']").focus();
  });

});
```

Comment: @DavidGonzalez https://jsfiddle.net/4mn2s3r9/1/ or https://jsfiddle.net/4mn2s3r9/

Answer (score 1):

This should work...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('button').click(function(e) {
   var targetForm = e.target.dataset.buttonFor
    $('form').addClass('hidden')
    $("."+targetForm).toggleClass('hidden')
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <label >Name:</label>
    <button type="button" data-button-for="first-name" style="margin-top:7px;"  class="toggle-new-form pull-right btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
    <p> Example first Name </p>
    <form  id="name-form" class="new-form first-name hidden" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
     <input> 
    </form>
    
    <hr>

    <div class="form-group" style="">
    <label >Shipping &amp; Addresses:</label>
    <button type="button" data-button-for="shipping-address" style="margin-top:7px;"  class="toggle-new-form pull-right btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
    <p> Example Last Name </p>
    </div>
    <form  id="name-form" class="new-form shipping-address hidden" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
    <input> 
    </form>
    
    <hr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to answer given by @madalin vascu, I would like to suggest that you should be using event delegation in this case.

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

Wrap all the forms in a `div` and call function like this:

`$('.divclass').on('click','[class^= "toggle-new-form"]',function() {});`

Check Out the jsfiddle:

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jagrati16/52amofbd/)